# Heroku can't find jquery.ui when using jquery-ui-rails gem in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, heroku

I'm using the [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) gem. It works fine on local host, but when I push to heroku it gives heroku logs shows this:

```
2012-04-11T02:28:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.slider'
2012-04-11T02:28:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:12)):
```

My production config file:

```
config.cache_classes = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.compress = true

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true
```

Some questions online say to change `config.assets.compile` to false, but when I do that I get a `application.css not precompiled` error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Taking the line `gem jquery-ui-rails` out of the `assets` group in the Gemfile seems to help. Similar problem/fix for the twitter bootstrap gem. :)

Comment: Would you know why this would solve it? It still seems like fundamentally, there are issues that aren't being solved.

Comment: Worked for me also. Same problem and fix for gem 'bootstrap-x-editable-rails', "~> 1.4.3" too

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar, though not identical, problem.  In my case, drag and drop methods worked locally, but Heroku complained that it couldn't find jquery-ui.

What solved it for me was this:

1. In the Gemfile, added

   **gem 'jquery-ui-rails'**
2. In application.js, added

   **//= require jquery.ui.all**
3. In application.css, added

   ***= require jquery.ui.all**

Finally, of course, `git commit -a -m "added jquery ui statements"`, followed by `git push heroku master`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have some sort of syntax error in some of your asset files. As the assets are precompiled different types of assets are concatenated as one. Now if one of your CSS files has a syntax error in the end of it, it might not affect anything in our local environment as the assets are not precompiled. However, when the asset files are joint together as one big file anything that then happens to follow the error would not get loaded. This might result in missing JavaScript stuff, CSS rules, etc..